# CKEditor custom toolbar WITH config.extraPlugins

Tags: javascript, editor, ckeditor

I'm currently using CKEeditor 4 and I'm using a custom toolbar set in config.js, but I would also like to add the justify plugin. Justify plugin works with the standard editor, but when I specify the custom toolbar, I'm unable to include it.

The difference I can see is that the default toolbar uses toolbarGroups, in which case I added 'align' to the 'paragraph' group.

The custom toolbar uses name/items (I couldn't get it to work with groups), and I tried to use 'align', 'Align', 'justify', 'Justify', etc... nothing shows the justification buttons.

Here is the specific portion of the config.js

```
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];


config.toolbar = 'ToolsNoImage';
config.toolbar_ToolsNoImage =
[
    { name: 'document', items : [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar','PageBreak'] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Source', '-', 'Preview' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','Align' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'About' ] }

];


config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
config.toolbarStartupExpanded = true;
config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
config.extraPlugins_ToolsNoImage = 'justify';
```

I feel like it's something very simple.. case issue, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple, indeed :D You used wrong button names. The group is named `'align'`, but buttons `'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'` not `'Align'` (you used this name in your configuration).

Also, this won't have any effect:

```
config.extraPlugins_ToolsNoImage = 'justify';
```

And this is rather not needed:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
```

But the most important thing is button names :)

BTW. There's a `plugins/toolbar/samples/toolbar.html` sample in every CKEditor package - it may help you finding the right names.

Answer (score 1):

This is for anyone struggling to enable alignment/justify options like I did.
To enable, the following is required as hanji suggested:

config.extraPlugins: 'justify'

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following to customize ckeditor toolbar for align and justify..

```
config.toolbar = [
        {name: "paragraph", 
         items: ["NumberedList", "BulletedList","Outdent","Indent","Blockquote","JustifyLeft","JustifyCenter","JustifyRight","JustifyBlock"]
        }
    ];
```

for further customization in toolbar you can refer to this page and simply edit your config.js:

http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Complete-list-of-toolbar-items